# Visual Studio Installer Setup Project

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I'm wondering how to use Setup Project in Visual Studio 15, which was in

> Solution -> Add -> New Project -> .../installed -> Other Project -> Types -> Visual Studio Installer ->Setup Project

but this disappeared. To create an `.EXE` file for a Windows Form Desktop application, it seems like it is no longer available.

Or how can I access the same functionality with higher versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension that brings it back for backwards compatibility. But at the same time the guidance has been to finally move to a Wix installer or some other installer technology.

The Installer projects are considered deprecated and bad. They can't be easily built using a CI server and more issues.

The proper solution would be:

- Use [Wix Installer project](http://wixtoolset.org/) (if you need Visual Studio project support)

  - [Simple tutorial](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/authoring_first_votive_project.html)
  - [Pluralsight](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/wix-introduction)
- Use something like [NullSoft Installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsis/) (just build the installer by building it outside of Visual Studio.

If you have an existing investment in the old style installer projects, [you can still use the extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects). **If you're building something new. DON'T**. It may be the simplest way of adding an installer, but it'll cause more issues in the long run.